# Texture taken from Item: can I make its filtering be gamma-correct?

Tags: qt, opengl, qtquick2, gamma, bilinear-interpolation

If this was a texture that I created, I'd simply make its internalFormat be `GL_SRGB`. But I'm passing a Qt Quick `Item` `foo` into my custom `QQuickFramebufferObject` GL code, where I take `foo->textureProvider()->texture()` and use that texture to render.

So can I make the filtering of the texture (when bilinearly sampling it) be gamma-correct?

**Note**: I'm aware I could implement manual bilinear filtering with 4 texture taps and lerping, but that would hurt performance somewhat, so I'm looking for a better way.

Or I could blit from the Qt Quick texture into a `GL_SRGB` texture of my own, then use that texture, but that's more complex and would need to happen every time the source texture is updated, hurting performance (and RAM usage).

I've searched google for hooks Qt may provide to configure this, but found nothing except QQuickTextureFactory which, however, does not solve my problem, at least AFAICS.

I need to support OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: How can this be "too broad"?

Comment: How should someone answer your question? Giving you the code/a link to existing code? Showing you a tutorial on how do to this? All of them are rather inappropriate for SO (too broad/off topic). Please show what you have tried.

Comment: @m7913d: Thx for the pointers on why I'm getting close votes. I'd be happy with a text description of the steps I need to take, if code is too much to ask for. Or just some broad pointers. I added info about my fruitless googling on the topic. And if googling produces no relevant Qt hooks, there's nothing I can try myself, since (a) I don't want to **change** the internal format of the texture (that would be slow and constitutes reaching deep into Qt internals), and (b) I can't change the initialization of the internalFormat, because it happens inside Qt code.

Answer (score 0):

> Note: I'm aware I could implement manual bilinear filtering with 4 texture taps and lerping, but that would hurt performance somewhat, so I'm looking for a better way.

Well, from the filtered result color, there is simply no way to get back the original colors used as input, even if you know the interpolation factors.

> Or I could blit from the Qt Quick texture into a GL_SRGB texture of my own, then use that texture, but that's more complex and would need to happen every time the source texture is updated, hurting performance (and RAM usage).

A more efficient variation of this strategy would be creating a second *view* onto the texture data, with an `SRGB` format (see [GL_ARB_texture_view extension](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/ARB/ARB_texture_view.txt), core since GL 4.3), which completely avoids the copy and additional RAM usage.

Comment: "Well, from the filtered result color, there is simply no way to get back the original colors used as input" - but if I floor() the texCoords and use GL_NEAREST filtering, I can. "Texture views" seemed like a perfect solution, but I need to support OpenGL ES 2.0, and texture views are [introduced in ES 3.1](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/EXT/EXT_texture_view.txt).

Comment: Yes. I did not mean that one cannot maually filter. I just wanted to make clear that there is not much one can do after one acuired the already (wrongly) filtered result, one must fetch the values before / without filtering in one way or the other. THere really isn't a better way. And for ES 2.0, I really don't see much options.